# How does the global npm modules run?

Tags: node.js, npm

I believe you can install npm modules globally with the switcher `-g`. For instance, if we install `express` with the `-g` switcher we can use the command `express` to generate a new app.

So how does it run without having to do something like `node express ...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of a property in the `package.json` file called `bin`.
When you use it in combination with the `-g` switch, `npm` automatically wraps the files and make them available in your system, because when you installed node, npm modules where already added to your `PATH`.

Here's an example of `package.json` using the `bin` property:

```
{
   "name": "mypackage",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "bin": {
      "mybin": "./lib/mybin.js",
      "myotherbin": "./lib/myotherbin.js"
   }
}
```

After installing this package globally, `mybin` and `myotherbin` will be available in your system.

[NPM docs for the bin property](https://npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#bin)